# Where have my date and time options gone for SQL Azure point in time restore?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Thankfully I don't need it at the moment but if I go to do a point in time restore on my Azure SQL database I don't see the date and time options any more.

When I go to the SQL Database blade in the Azure portal, click on a database and then click the Restore button I see this in the Restore pane which I've not seen before:

[image: DatabaseRestoreParemeterProviderPart thingy in Sql Azure]

If I click on it I can continue to the restore options but there are no date and time controls displayed:

[image: Missing date and time controls]

Am I doing it wrong or is this a bug? I did once (a fair while ago) do a point in time restore on this database where I choose a specific date and time so I know it worked at one point. It's been like this for at least the last two days for me.

Answer (score 1):

I checked again today and the controls were back!

Same browser, same method - Sql database, click on database, click restore. The DatabaseRestoreParameterProviderPart thing was gone and the date and time controls were back, after having been awol for at least two days.

So not really an answer - but whatever the problem was I'm back to normal now.

Comment: David- Your blade with those controls was showing a crash or a generic unavailability of the blade. I am unsure why they were temporarily unavailable and will make sure the team has investigated, but I don't have an actionable answer at this time. Please ensure that you filed a support ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could see those options in both old portal and new portal..

[image]

Only reason i could think of on,why you are not seeing those options is

1.Your database may be recent
2.I don't see extension which you are seeing,so you might be in wrong path

I clicked restore from overview screen..

[image]

You might have to contact support,if you are not seeing them still after trying from seperate browser